# The JSON data returned from the web service is showing undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am calling a web service through jquery ajax call. The response returned from the service seem to be fine when checking in the browser as shown below:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"Table":[{"stgr_grn_no":"H1B1G00679","stgr_slno":1174.0}]}
</string>
```

when i get the same through jquery ajax call, it is showing as undefined.

```
 var param = {GRNNumber: GRNNumber};              
         $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                datatype: "json",
                url: url,       
                data: param,    
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                },
                success: (function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                     var cont = data.Table; 
                     alert(cont);
                     for (var i in cont) 
                     {
                         alert(cont[i].stgr_grn_no);

                     }      

                }),

                error: (function(request, status){
                var err = status + ", " + JSON.stringify(request) + "ERROR:";   
                alert(err);
            })


          });
```

Here the "data" is showing as object Document ,
 "cont" is showing as undefined.
When i try to alert the "jqxhr" parameter it is showing all the data from the web service and the status is OK. 
I tried in most of the posts and blogs but couldn't find where i went wrong. Please help.

Comment: But the response is XML, XML containing JSON - not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"Table":[{"stgr_grn_no":"H1B1G00679","stgr_slno":1174.0}]}
</string>
```

… is not JSON. It is XML with some JSON instead it.

As approaches for passing data about go, this is crazy. You should fix the web service so it either just returns the JSON or so that it expresses the data in pure XML instead of a mix of XML and JSON.

If you can't do that, then you must first parse the Ajax response as XML, extract the JSON from it (it will be something like `rootElement.firstChild.data`) and then parse that as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var cont = data.Table;    
alert(cont);
```

there is no `st_grn` in your JSON object.

As a tip:
Change to `console.log(data)` and firebug for Firefox (or equal debugging system) to dig deeper into the object. Makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: sorry i mistakenly mentioned  data.st_grn. Its data.table only and it is showing undefined.